# How to get back the ALT +TAB functionality?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, gnome-classic

I lost the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality.
How to get it back?

Note:

- I m using Ubuntu 12.04 **without Unity**
- I m using **Gnome classic (no effects)** session
- so **the Unity plug-in is deselected** in **compizconfig settings manager** for performance purpose.
- I have same settings on an other PC, and on this PC the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality is running fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **NOTE**: You must use the normal Classic Session if you want to use compiz's functions

To fix this:

Firstly, install `ccsm` if you haven't already using

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

and type in `ccsm` in the terminal

You'll get this window

[image]

Scroll down and select the checkmark on the left of "Application Switcher":

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works. Note that I have `ccsm` installed with Gnome Classic no effect (gnome-fallback)

Comment: When I installed ccsm there was no option for application switcher listed under window management.... How do I get that option?

Comment: @NickHalden: You need to install `compiz-plugins` to make it available